# Retrieve files from broken Samsung Galaxy S 4

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen

I ended up stepping on my phone and cracking it to the point where I can see ink (liquid) coming out of the cracks. I need to know if there's some way I can get back photos and files off of it. There are a couple of catches though:

1. The phone is locked by a pattern
2. The screen is completely broken, does not respond to touch.
3. The panel (home, back, search) is broken, and does not light up.
4. Sound does not work (hitting the volume up button to the max does not make the beep I am accustomed to, and the start up noise does not play).
5. It does not show up with ADB (even after installing the "universal ADB drivers")
6. When I plug it in, it shows up in the explorer, but no files are visible.
7. It shows up in Kies, but again, it's locked.
8. Most of these files were stored on the internal memory, as I let my girlfriend use my SD card.
9. MOBOROBO does not recognize that a device is connected.
10. The USB A Male to USB B Micro adapter does not work, and keyboard input and mouse input don't work.
11. Bluetooth was not on before it broke (and is still not on).
12. Wifi was not on, and is still not on.
13. I did not have a Samsung account associated with my phone, so I am unable to unlock it via the Samsung website.

Is there any way that I can retrieve any data? I think I've nearly exhausted all of the suggestions I've seen (e.g. from the [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)). I did have Lookout installed, and I told it to backup the data (I was able to scream with the device somehow), but it hasn't showed up yet.

Comment: I have a feeling the device is completely broken, rather than just the screen. It sounds like the chipset is cracked. If it's that broken it's pretty much dead.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Zymus! I've integrated that with your question directly, so we can delete the comments now (note you always can [edit] your question to include further details – makes them easier to spot than in comments).